# Retrieve Data from Internal Storage DEFINED in a class ANDROID

Tags: android, methods, save, storage, internal

I have defined two subclasses LoadData() and SaveData() in a Class to load and save data in the Internal Storage as:

```
public class LoadSaveInternalActivity extends Activity {
public String LoadData(String filename)
{   String read = "";
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput(filename);
        if (fis != null) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            read = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return read;
}

public void SaveData(String data, String filename)
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = getBaseContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = data;
        outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

And I am trying to call these methods of the class from another Activity like:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

EditText edittxt;
private final static String file_name = "myfile";
private LoadSaveInternalActivity InternalActivity;@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container,false);

    edittxt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTxt);

    InternalActivity = new LoadSaveInternalActivity();
    String readData = InternalActivity.LoadData(file_name);
    edittxt.setText(readData);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    InternalActivity = new LoadSaveInternalActivity();
    InternalActivity.SaveData(edittxt.getText().toString(),file_name);

}
```

But it doesn't work out. Does anybody can help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have defined two subclasses LoadData() and SaveData() in a Class

Those are *methods*. They are not *subclasses*.

```
public class LoadSaveInternalActivity extends Activity
```

Do **not** create random subclasses of `Activity`.

```
InternalActivity = new LoadSaveInternalActivity();
```

Do **not** create instances of an `Activity` yourself via the constructor.

The simplest set of fixes would be:

Step #1: Move your load and save methods into your fragment

Step #2: Change the `getBaseContext()` calls to `getActivity()` in those methods

Step #3: Change `onCreateView()` and `onStop()` to call the load and save methods in the fragment

Step #4: Delete `LoadSaveInternalActivity` and all references to it

That code should at least compile and run. It is still fairly poor code (e.g., you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread).

> But it doesn't work out

In the future, when you post questions on Stack Overflow, explain **in detail** what your symptoms are. Statements like "it doesn't work out", without any details, are useless.

Comment: Actually I need to define them in another class and not in the fragment itself. Since I need to access them from other classes as well. When I define them in the fragment, everything is fine.

Comment: @srt: Then define them `static` methods somewhere, where they take a `Context` as a parameter. Use that `Context` instead of `getBaseContext()` in your original code. Use `getActivity()` in your fragment to get a `Context` to pass into the methods.

Comment: By somewhere do you mean in a new class? Like this:
static LoadData(Context c, String filename)

Comment: @srt: "By somewhere do you mean in a new class?" -- that is up to you. "Like this" -- yes.